# I am trying to install linux on my new Lenovo 5G

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop, arm

I am trying now for some time to install Linux on my new Lenovo 5G laptop as stand alone without success.

Laptop spec.:

Qualcomm Snapdragon 8cx Gen2 5G processor (Octa-Core)
8 GB LPDDR4X-1866
512 GB UFS 3.0
Adreno 680 Grafik shared VRAM

I tried the current version of:

Ubuntu arm server lts
Debian arm64
and some modified .iso i found on github and blogpost for the Lenovo C630.

Sometimes i can boot into the installation menu and get asked if i want to install, graphical install etc, after clicking on it, the laptop just reboots and the installation menu pops up again or he reboots in an endless loop.

With the .iso for the Lenovo C630 i had an partial success, at least i was able to go through the hole installation process, but after the reboot i get the error message that i need an windows recovery drive, I was partitioning everything in one during installation to have ubuntu as stand alone.

My thought was maybe the bootloader wasn't installed properly, so i wanted to use a live usb stick with linux to boot into that one and install grub by hand. Unfortunatley i cant boot into the live versions of arm64 i found so far.

Comment: are you picking the non-graphical install?

Comment: Non graphical and graphical have I tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm Snapdragon 8cx Gen2 5G aka SC8180XP is currently not supported by the linux kernel.

- Snapdragon 8cx Gen 1 [SC8180X](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/log/?qt=grep&q=SC8180X) [support 6.1+](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/commit/?id=40285e64c5654c956505dad34ed2ee4be163b1f0)
- Snapdragon 8cx Gen 2 [SC8180XP](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/log/?qt=grep&q=SC8180XP) unknown
- Snapdragon 8cx Gen 3 [SC8280](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/log/?qt=grep&q=SC8280)
  complete support 5.19+

Have you tried with [this](https://github.com/aarch64-laptops/debian-cdimage)?

Comment: I have tried the link already, after trying aarch64 I think I have done some mistakes and haven't followed all instructions in the post correctly. I will try again and post an update.

Comment: Gave it some more tries, problem now is i dont have windows anymore, from which i should get the firmware. After the installion i cant do the grub cmds correctly and hit walls, because of missing files. 

I am trying right now to do a new installtion of windows, the problem i face here is , my keyboard and touchpad doesnt work during the process, because its usb c port's, i have to go and buy another usb port converter, to be able to have plugged in the installtion medium and a external keyboard maybe that will work.

Lenovo support is unable to help me with the new installtion, so far.

Comment: The latest debian unstable supports the 6.1 kernel and the snapdragon 8cx Gen 2 SoC (which is therefore equivalent to Gen 1 except for the CPU frequency) and is able to start the installer even if the touchpad and keyboard do not work.